# Disabling mathastext in middle of the document

Tags: mathastext

Is it possible to disable and enable `mathastext` in the middle of the document for a line or paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if it was loaded with option `subdued`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% font packages
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage[subdued, defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}

% define a math version to use NewCentury font
\Mathastext[newcent]

% now define another one to have letter italic
% (but not digits or operator names)
\MTlettershape{it}
\Mathastext[newcentit]

\DeclareMathOperator\per{per}

\begin{document}
% At start mathastext is unactivated.

Text in NewCentury but math is as in default
\begin{multline}
\biggl(\sum_{\,i\in\mathbf{n}}a_{l_i}x_i\biggr)
\det\mathbf{K}(t=1,x_1,\dots,x_n;l |l )\\
=\biggl(\prod_{\,i\in\mathbf{n}}\hat x_i\biggr)
\sum_{I\subseteq\mathbf{n}-\{l \}}
(-1)^{|I|}\per\mathbf{A}^{(\lambda)}(I|I)
\det\mathbf{A}^{(\lambda)}
(\overline I\cup\{l \}|\overline I\cup\{l \}).
\end{multline}

Now with \verb|mathastext| active in math using upright letters.
\MTversion{newcent}
\begin{multline}
\biggl(\sum_{\,i\in\mathbf{n}}a_{l_i}x_i\biggr)
\det\mathbf{K}(t=1,x_1,\dots,x_n;l |l )\\
=\biggl(\prod_{\,i\in\mathbf{n}}\hat x_i\biggr)
\sum_{I\subseteq\mathbf{n}-\{l \}}
(-1)^{|I|}\per\mathbf{A}^{(\lambda)}(I|I)
\det\mathbf{A}^{(\lambda)}
(\overline I\cup\{l \}|\overline I\cup\{l \}).
\end{multline}

Now with italic letters again from New Century font.
\MTversion{newcentit}
\begin{multline}
\biggl(\sum_{\,i\in\mathbf{n}}a_{l_i}x_i\biggr)
\det\mathbf{K}(t=1,x_1,\dots,x_n;l |l )\\
=\biggl(\prod_{\,i\in\mathbf{n}}\hat x_i\biggr)
\sum_{I\subseteq\mathbf{n}-\{l \}}
(-1)^{|I|}\per\mathbf{A}^{(\lambda)}(I|I)
\det\mathbf{A}^{(\lambda)}
(\overline I\cup\{l \}|\overline I\cup\{l \}).
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In example above, `\MTversion{normal}` to again "deactivate" `mathastext`. But as explained in documentation this "deactivate" is only to 99%. Some of its actions are not reversible, because it was not initially designed for reversibility.